# Microsoft Report Builder query designer named pipe errors on different client workstations

Tags: reporting-services, named-pipes, reportbuilder, query-designer

I use RB at home to edit reports on a remote report server.  I have three different machines at home.  On all 3, I log into the report server the exact same way, and on all 3 I can run or edit any report.  However, if I try to access the query designer, I get failures on 2 of the 3 machines.  The machine that succeeds is running RB version 14.0.1016.246 on Windows 10 Pro, and the ones that fail are RB 15.0.20073.0, one on Windows 10 Home and one on Windows 11 Pro.  The Data Source credentials are explicitly specified every time, and the error I get is " Named Pipes Provider, error: 40".  I'm not a networking or a security expert, but I understand that to the remote server, my IP address is the same no matter which machine I'm on.  I should mention that I do not administer the Report Server, the Data Source, or the network on which they're installed.  I'm trying to retire the machine that works (the RB version should tell you how old it is), but I can't until I can edit a query from another machine.

I tried to copy the 14.0.1016.246 version to the Windows 11 machine and run it there, but got the same error.  I don't want to upgrade the machine that works, because I don't want to lose my only working version.

Comment: I changed the connection string in the Data Source to force tcp.  I still get an error on all but the old machine, only this time it's a TCP error.  At this point I think it's something that defaults differently in the two RB versions.  It's not finding the database, regardless of protocol.